# eclipse 3.5.2 how to add a new server?

Tags: eclipse

I just download eclipse 3.5.2 and I'm trying to add a tomcat server.
But I just can't seem to find where the server view is.
I thought it used to be in view => show views => server but it doesn't appear to be there.
Does anyone know where they moved it to?

Comment: By 3.5.2 you mean the Galileo version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you downloaded Eclipse plain Java version instead of [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR2/eclipse-jee-galileo-SR2-win32.zip) distribution.

If this, you can install Java EE plugins via Eclipse Update Manager. Then you can see "servers" window.

Answer (score 2):

You should find it under Window->Show View->Servers. If you don't find Servers in the View popup then you can try the Window->Show View->Others->Server->Servers. 
It can also be done using File->New->Other->Server->Server

Answer (score 1):

1- You should try this way : Help >> Install New Software

2- And then select your eclipse in Work with section. For example:  ["Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno(i'm    using this version)"]

3- And then click   ((Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development))

4- After all process enjoy to click servers section in window >> show windows >> other >> server   >> servers !!!